# cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'A' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '^[A-Za-z]?$' for type 'whatever'

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

Here's the particular XML tag whose validation is failing:

```
<MiddleName>A</MiddleName>
```

The XSD for that tag:

```
<xsd:element name="MiddleName" type="MiddleInitial" />

<xsd:simpleType name="MiddleInitial">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="^[A-Za-z]?$" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The error I'm getting:

```
cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'A' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '^[A-Za-z]?$' for type 'MiddleInitial'.
```

The validator I'm using:

http://tools.decisionsoft.com/schemaValidate/

The regular expression looks good.  ^ matches the start, $, the end, ? is for zero or one times the letters A-Z or a-z.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the w3 spec [Regular Expressions (Appendix D)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#regexAppendix):

> ...expressions are matched against entire lexical representations
>   rather than user-scoped lexical representations such as line and
>   paragraph. For this reason, the expression language does not contain
>   the metacharacters ^ and $, although ^ is used to express exception,
>   e.g. [^0-9]x

I.e. take out the `^` and `$`.