# RegEx in XSD java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate an `XML` against a `XSD` with `Java` but I have some problems with a `regex`.

The `regex` is `^\w+\.pdf$`. That means, a valid `pdf` file name (it must end with `.pdf`). I've checked it on https://regex101.com/ and it works for "document.pdf" but not for `document.pdff` or `document.pdf` which means the `regex` is correct.

When validating the XML against the `XSD` with `Java`, I get the following error:

> ***Value 'document.pdf' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '^\w+.pdf$' for type 'pdfDocumentType'***.

Please, any help?

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Did you try to escape the period? Try using \. for a literal period character. (. means any single character and might have a side effect here)

Comment: @SurfMan Omitting the escape for the period will accept more that actually expected but it cannot be the reason for refusing the correct "document.pdf".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently ^ and $ are not necessary/allowed here.

See answer here: [cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'A' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '^[A-Za-z]?$' for type 'whatever'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622869/cvc-pattern-valid-value-a-is-not-facet-valid-with-respect-to-pattern-a-za)

Comment: Check the appendix in XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes. And the section on  pattern facets: a pattern must match the entire value; therefore `^` and `$` are not "magic".

Comment: Hi SurfMan, If I take out ^ it will accept "*document.pdf" as valid. If I take out $ it will accept "document.pdff" as valid. what I want is ALFANUMERIQUE + ".pdf".

Comment: How do you check that? Which tool says it's invalid? Got a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by any chance?

Comment: @SurfMan: Your "answer" should instead have been a vote to close a duplicate, especially given that you're merely echoing what's in the Q/A link you provide.

Comment: @pianist.qaissi: SurfMan is right to point you in the direction of a similar question where the answer more thoroughly explains (with proper W3C citation) that in XSD, the regex have implied `^` and `$` anchoring at the ends.

Comment: @kjhughes I just started answering questions on SO. I'll read up on how to do votes. Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the code I use:

```
    InputStream xmlIs = null;
    InputStream xsdIs = null;

    try {
        xmlIs = (new FileInputStream(xmlFile));
        xsdIs = (new FileInputStream(xsdFile));

        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsdIs));
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlIs));
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```